# How Can I saved a pdf file that cannot be saved?

Tags: windows, adobe-acrobat

I want to highlight the important sentences in a pdf file, but when I want to save the changes, an error pops up entitled "The document could not be saved. There was a problem reading this document (110)."  I need to say that I am using Adobe Acrobat PDF reader XI on Windows 8.1. The link for downloading the pdf file is provided here in bellow: http://frank.villaro-dixon.eu/public_upload/Probability,_Statistics,_and_Random_Processes_for_Eletrical_Engineerging,_3rd_Ed_-_Leon-Garcia.pdf

Comment: Same issue occur on my side after I download and make some modification. It would be caused by the PDF itself.

Answer (score 1):

Either the original file is already corrupted, or it got corrupted during the download or/and handling.

A few things you can do:

• Re-download the document.

• Switch through all the pages of the document; if no error occurs, the document is OK.

• Do a simple Save (instead of Save as…).

• Update your Acrobat Reader and try again.

HTH.